# Printing full document with PySide/Qt

Tags: python, qt, printing, pyside

Currently I'm busy with developing an application which converts a PDF to PNG and uses the PNG image to print it out to a printer.

The problem is that I can print out an image, but I don't understand how to resize it in a way that it's always full-size on the paper. Offcourse I want to set some margins, but the image has to be re-sized in a way that it fits exactly.

The problem is that I really don't have a clue how to do this, since the documentation is very limited.

This is my current code to print the image:

```
#set up printer
printer = QtGui.QPrinter(QtGui.QPrinter.HighResolution)
printer.setPrinterName('Adobe PDF') #I print to my Adobe PDF software printer
#set up image
image = QtGui.QImage(pngFiles[0])
#paint & print
painter = QtGui.QPainter()
painter.begin(printer)
painter.drawImage(100,100, image)
painter.end()
```

I think the solution is in this line:
    painter.drawImage(100,100, image)

It gives the image a margin of 100 from the sides, but it does not scale. How can I scale the image in a way that it fits the document? I'm especially looking for a solution that looks to the default document size of the printer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the conversation with Sashoalm I could make  resize the image and fit it nicely on the paper for printing. I've stripped down my expirmental code and it should work like this.

```
from PIL import Image
imagefile = 'image.png'

def scale(w, h, x, y, maximum=True):
    nw = y * w / h
    nh = x * h / w
    if maximum ^ (nw >= x):
        return nw or 1, y
    return x, nh or 1

#set up print printer.
printer = QtGui.QPrinter(QtGui.QPrinter.HighResolution)
#dlg = QtGui.QPrintDialog(printer, self)
printer.setPrinterName('Adobe PDF')

#check image size with PIL:  
image = Image.open(imagefile)
imageWidth, imageHeight = image.size

paperPixels = printer.pageRect(QtGui.QPrinter.DevicePixel)
paperPixels = paperPixels.getRect() #get tuple of the "pixels on the paper"
paperWidth = paperPixels[2]
paperHeight = paperPixels[3]

#set margins for paper
paperMargin = 100
#find out the image size
paperWidth = paperWidth - (paperMargin*2) #times two, for left and right.. 
paperHeight = paperHeight - (paperMargin*2)

#scale image within a rectangle.
paintWidth, paintHeight = scale(imageWidth, imageHeight, paperWidth, paperHeight, True)            
#construct the paint dimensions area
paintRect = QtCore.QRectF(paperMargin, paperMargin, paintWidth, paintHeight)

#start painting
image = QtGui.QImage(imagefile)
painter = QtGui.QPainter()
painter.begin(printer)
painter.drawImage(paintRect, image)
painter.end()
#now the page gets printed out and the image should fit the paper.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the document's size using [QPrinter::paperSize](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprinter.html#paperSize-2).

For resizing the image when drawing it, use the overloaded version of [QPainter::drawImage](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#drawImage-7) which takes a QRectF, not a QPoint. The image will then be scaled to fit in the destination QRectF.

Comment: I really didn't understand what you said, sorry. By the way, I have only limited experience with python, I use Qt with C++. Why aren't those functions working for you?

Comment: I deleted my comment at the same time as you answered it.

I don't understand you exactly. When I do: papersize = QtGui.QPrinter.paperSize(printer). papersize is PySide.QtGui.QPrinter.PageSize.A4.. an I doing it right until now? or do i have to implement it different? 

Maybe you could tell me how you would do it in C++ code, maybe I can translate it to Python.

Comment: So your question is solved - paperSize gave you the PageSize - it's A4. What more do you need? A4 is a standard paper size, you know that, right? See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_size

Comment: Yes, I know that, but after I get it back I don't know what do do with it in order to make is useful. If I execute QtGui.QPrinter.PageSize.A4 it gives the same back..

Comment: "I'm especially looking for a solution that looks to the default document size of the printer", is this not what you wanted? To get the document size of the printer I mean. It's in your question. I gave you the function that gives you that - `QPrinter::papersize`.

Comment: I want to make the image on the document scale with the document size. So if it's A3 the image will scale until A3 size. If it's A4 it will scale until its A4 size.

Now I know the papersize, but I keeps crashing when I want to use it in my painter.drawimage. I don't really how to do it together with the QRectF and stuff like you describe in your answer.

Could you elaborate your answer with some code to make it working? Maybe I can translate it then to a working python script.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28833/discussion-between-sashoalm-and-ecno92)

Comment: After a small chat with sashoalm I found the solution, but I have to work it out a little in order to make it work perfectly. I'll post it when its done.